# LEFT JOIN on empty table NULLs results

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

When I join a table that is empty and add it to the **kills_total** field, kills_total values show **NULL**.

```
SELECT 
       alias.name alias, team.name team, sid.steam_id steam_id,
       (SUM(ws1.kills) + SUM(ws2.kills) + SUM(spnr.kills)) kills_total
FROM pickup
            JOIN player ON player.pickup_id = pickup.id
            JOIN team ON player.team_id = team.id
            JOIN sid ON player.sid_id = sid.id
            JOIN alias ON player.alias_id = alias.id
            LEFT JOIN weapon_stats_1 ws1 ON ws1.pickup_id = pickup.id AND ws1.player_id = player.id
            LEFT JOIN weapon_stats_2 ws2 ON ws2.pickup_id = pickup.id AND ws2.player_id = player.id
            LEFT JOIN spanner_stats spnr ON spnr.pickup_id = pickup.id AND spnr.player_id = player.id
WHERE pickup.logfile_name = 'srv-20130725-2151-log' GROUP BY player.id ORDER BY kills_total DESC
```

This is the outcome:

[image: fail]

```
SELECT 
       alias.name alias, team.name team, sid.steam_id steam_id,
       (SUM(ws1.kills) + SUM(ws2.kills)) kills_total
FROM pickup
            JOIN player ON player.pickup_id = pickup.id
            JOIN team ON player.team_id = team.id
            JOIN sid ON player.sid_id = sid.id
            JOIN alias ON player.alias_id = alias.id
            LEFT JOIN weapon_stats_1 ws1 ON ws1.pickup_id = pickup.id AND ws1.player_id = player.id
            LEFT JOIN weapon_stats_2 ws2 ON ws2.pickup_id = pickup.id AND ws2.player_id = player.id
WHERE pickup.logfile_name = 'srv-20130725-2151-log' GROUP BY player.id ORDER BY kills_total DESC
```

This is the result when I am removing the empty table from the query:

[image]

How do I join the **spanner_stats** table and just do nothing (ie. SUM(0)) if its empty, so **ws1** and **ws2** values are SUM()med up and displayed in **kills_total** even when the third table that is being joined has no single row matching **"thirdTable.pickup_id = pickup.id AND thirdTable.player_id = player.id"**?

Comment: It looks like all you are missing is translating NULLs from the SUM into zeros. The shorthand way to do this is to use the `IFNULL()` function, the more portable SQL-92 would be the an equivalent CASE expresssion  `CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE a END`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
       alias.name alias, team.name team, sid.steam_id steam_id,
       (SUM(IFNULL(ws1.kills,0)) + SUM(IFNULL(ws2.kills,0)) + SUM(IFNULL(spnr.kills,0))) kills_total
FROM pickup
            JOIN player ON player.pickup_id = pickup.id
            JOIN team ON player.team_id = team.id
            JOIN sid ON player.sid_id = sid.id
            JOIN alias ON player.alias_id = alias.id
            LEFT JOIN weapon_stats_1 ws1 ON ws1.pickup_id = pickup.id AND ws1.player_id = player.id
            LEFT JOIN weapon_stats_2 ws2 ON ws2.pickup_id = pickup.id AND ws2.player_id = player.id
            LEFT JOIN spanner_stats spnr ON spnr.pickup_id = pickup.id AND spnr.player_id = player.id
WHERE pickup.logfile_name = 'srv-20130725-2151-log' GROUP BY player.id ORDER BY kills_total DESC
```

Essentially you are telling MySql to use 0 instead of `NULL`  if there is no record for the left join. Have a look at IFNULL() http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp.

The SQL SUM() function returns NULL if any of the components are NULL I believe.

Comment: Sorry you're right, too much MS SQL Server here :) Will update answer

Comment: Accepted it, I got the point, thank you very much! IFNULL works perfectly

Comment: The only case when [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) returns `NULL` is when return set is empty.  [Group functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) **ignore NULL values**. Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/17080) demo

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using [IFNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

> **IFNULL(expr1,expr2)**
>
> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns
>   expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the
>   context in which it is used.

Have a look at the Below example to demonstrate the differences.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6a24/4)